# executing a command without password prompt or root

Tags: centos, permissions, file-permissions, rhel8, minikube

For the sake of writing a script, I'd like my minikube-role-user to execute the command `minikube tunnel` without a password prompt, without switching user to root, be it by su or temporarily by sudo, or permanently with visudo.

I have tried giving my minikube-role-user the executable permission for, and ownership of, the executable /bin/minikube and /usr/bin/minikube but the password prompt persists. I don't think the minikube executable prompts for a password itself, I think it just executes a second executable that I don't have permission for and need to discover so I can get permission for it. I suspect this because the minikibe tunnel command doesn't prompt for a password immediately, does print some stdout before and after prompting for the password, and other minikube commands don't prompt for a password. I thought this hypothetical second executable maybe nftables because minikube tunnel may write an nftables rule, but giving my minikube-role-user ownership permissions of nftables did not get rid of the password prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux `minikube tunnel` [uses hard-coded `sudo` under-the-hood](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/d70d10eef3fe56ebda4b133c6feb5162b044ad48/pkg/minikube/tunnel/route_linux.go#L41), as such you won't get around `visudo` / adjusting `sudoers`.

I think you already found what [the minikube docs say on avoiding password prompts](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#avoiding-password-prompts) and want something more granular than giving access to `sudo ip`.

`/etc/sudoers` can configure `sudo` quite granular, you can also allow password-less `sudo` for *specific* commands only:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ip route add 10.96.0.0/12 via 192.168.64.194
```

- the `10.96.0.0/12` is the cluster's service CIDR
  here the default and most likely also yours, otherwise [check this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190607).
- the `192.168.64.194` is your `minikube ip`

I unfortunately cannot test this right now, but maybe it is you worth a try :)

Comment: if my answer helped you, consider marking it as the accepted one. :)

Comment: For stopping the minikube tunnel without a password prompt, I appended your sudoers statement with ```/usr/sbin/ip route delete 10.96.0.0/12```